# Why can't I make any Tinkers Construct parts with iron?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tinkers-construct, minecraft-hexxit

I was trying to build an iron hatchet today, but suddenly I noticed I couldn't make any part with iron! Any other material like cobblestone or wood works, but not Iron. It just doesn't show anything on the right.

[image]

I think it has something to do with the new Hexxit Update. A few days ago I had made an iron Mattock, but after updating yesterday I can't. You can actually see the mattock there in the hotbar.

Am I the only one? Is it a bug? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [Minecraft Forum post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1659892-15xtinkers-construct/) for Tinkers Construct, and this is at the top of the post:

> Metal parts, including iron, have to be made with metal casts and the Smeltery. Casts are crafted by pouring Aluminum Brass/Gold on a tool part.

Comment: whao! thankk you so much! that was really helpful. I guess it must be the nw tinkers Contruct update then! Thank you

Comment: @kwan Since this seems to have helped, it is custom to click the "accept answer" checkmark - that way Duffman3005 gets a 15 rep bonus (and don't forget you can upvote now)